# How to practically apply Grimm and Verner's law to english and Spanish

Tags: etymology, grimms-law

I am a beginner in linguistics and don't know many details about the field of study in general, but, for a beginner, is there anything that shows how english and spanish are related through those laws in general? I looked online but found only general charts that largely detailed PIE to english or to early germanic languages.

Comment: The most obvious examples of Grimm's law correspondences between modern English and Spanish: f in father and foot = p in padre and pie, th in three = t in tres, t in two and ten = d in dos and diez

Comment: Others: f in fish = p in pez, th in thou = t in tú, h in head, hundred, heart, horn = c in cabeza, cien/ciento, corazón, cuerno; wh/h in English question words = cu/qu/c in Spanish question words